# Route traffic from switch through DNS before main router

Tags: networking, dns, routing

So we want to do a lan party with <25 people. The bandwith avaible at that location is about 8Mbit (so not that fast). So we decided to set up a server as cache server for downloads on Steam ([Steamcache](http://steamcache.net/)). What we need to do is set the DNS for every computer to a DNS on that steamcache server.

So i was wondering if there is a way to route the traffic from all PCs to that DNS **without chaing the router's DNS** or **every DNS setting on that PCs**? All PCs are connected to one Managed Gigabit switch. I have one other ***additonal router*** avaible for use, if that helps.

I'll add some pitures here if that helps:

[setup how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WN33L.png) (The steamcache server checks if the package the user wants is allready on the server. If so it sends it locally. Otherwise it will download it -> saveit to the cache -> send it to the user)

My idea is to set the 2. routers DNS to the Steamcache-dns. But this wont work because the 2. router (fritz box 3272) is set to use the 1. routers LAN Cable as connection to the internet and then creates a new network. I'm somehow not able to set the DNS on the 2. router. There is no tab in the config to do that.

Comment: You're essentially trying to poison DNS on the network which isn't a great idea. Try looking in the DHCP settings of your router, there has to be an option. What's the router model? Wouldn't it be faster anyways just to ask everyone to switch DNS? It's a five minute process at most.

Comment: Yeah you're probably right there. The main routers model is a FritzBox 7490. The problem is that I don't want to change anything in that main router.